# Fallo al guardar elementos en MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

se me está presentando un problema. Al introducir datos en un HTML y enviarlos a la base de datos de MongoDB se me envian los elementos vacios, es decir, los atributos que se guardan  no contienen los datos que introduzco en el html. Aquí os enseño el ejemplo:

```
addItem = function(req, res) {
 console.log('POST');
 console.log(req.body.nid);
 console.log(req.body.valor);

 var myData = new Item({
    nid:    req.body.nid,
    valor:    req.body.valor
 });

 myData.save().then(item => {
    res.send("item saved to database");
 })

 res.send(myData);}
```

Aquí podeis ver mi html:

```
 <body>
     <h1>Into to Node and MongoDB</h1>
     <form method="post" action="/item">
         <label>Inserte los datos</label><br>
         <input type="text" name="nid" id="nid" placeholder="Enter NID" required>
         <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" placeholder="Enter VALOR" required>
         <input type="submit" value="Add Name">
     </form>       
 </body>
```

El esquema del objeto que guardo en la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
    var itemSchema = new Schema({
        nid:        { type: String },
        valor:      { type: String }
   });
```

Por otra parte tengo la base de datos creada en local y como podéis ver estos son los objetos que se me guardan al ejecutar hacer un envió del formulario:

```
    > db.items.find()
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5acca9569b59cf26e7b1e531"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5acca95a9b59cf26e7b1e532"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5acca9c5fd2b102aac692f39"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accab52e7cc932cb51a67ad"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accab56e7cc932cb51a67ae"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accab72e7cc932cb51a67af"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accab8fe7cc932cb51a67b0"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accabb5e7cc932cb51a67b1"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accabc0e7cc932cb51a67b2"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accabe18e815d2eb13969e6"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accabea8e815d2eb13969e7"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accac38946e422ec6312fe6"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accac757417922eda570a3b"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accacc8d0f18130c5df8f0b"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accaff13281d731777f0196"), "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5accb13426572b337fd0f64b"), "__v" : 0 }
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, y gracias de antemano, cualquier modificación o consejo por vuestra parte me será de gran ayuda para seguir aprendiendo y prácticando.

Comment: Los `console.log` que tienes en tu función de guardar que imprimen?, que servidor estas usando? Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegúrate de las propiedades `req.body.nid` y `req.body.valor` contengan datos.
En caso de que intentes guardar alguna propiedad cuyo valor que sea undefined, MongoDB no la creará.
Comprueba el valor de estas propiedades y en caso de que sean undefined, revisa que estés usando la librería body-parser, ya que de lo contrario el cuerpo de la petición HTTP no estará disponible en `req.body`
Otra cosa que puede estar pasando es que no le envíes los datos en el formato correcto al servidor, asegúrate de que si el body-parser está configurado para parsear JSON, le envíes los datos en este formato.